# AWS-EC2 Ubuntu How to force root user UBUNTU to login using both Key and Password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am working on the instance of ubuntu with latest version

I want to setup a Root user ubuntu to login Forcefully using both key and password

So where i can do this configuration

I tried **SSHD_CONFIG** using
**PermitRootLogin** & **PasswordAuthentication** Yes
But didnt worked

Can please guide me someone. is this something needs to be done on the instance level

Answer (score 0):

You must set `PubkeyAuthentication yes` and `PasswordAuthentication yes` if you require both methods to log in.

Make sure to restart sshd after making configuration changes.